# Theme options messing

Tags: php, wordpress

I downloaded woovina Themplate in my local PC to create a website.
I want to change images in my slider body taken from demo themplate, i visit so many sites advising me to search for "theme options" as one of the steps i must follow to change the slider image in wordpress. I didn't find it in Apperance > Customise !.
Can you help me to find "options theme" and if you have solution about changing slider image it will be better.
i took the free template from [Google](http://www.woovina.com/)

Comment: Woovina apparently offers one month of free support, so why not try asking them for help directly?

Comment: I actually asked them but they didn't reply me ..